# How can I keep the UI responsive and updated with progress while all the work is done in a background job on the local computer?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, progress, xen, start-job

I have a program that displays a `UI`, allows the user to pick virtual machine names obtained by querying the `Xen` pool master server, and then creates snapshots for the selected virtual machines. I want the snapshots to be created in the background so I can keep the `UI` responsive and update the `UI` with progress as each snapshot is created.

Originally, I connected to the `Xen` pool master server and then executed the `Xen` create snapshot cmdlet once per selected VM in the `UI` thread. As such, the `UI` became unresponsive.

Next, I connected to the `Xen` pool master server and then did a `start-job` (`background job`) once per VM to create the VM's snapshot. This failed because the `Xen` session created in the `UI` thread could not be passed to the `background job` (The content of the session variable makes it into the block, but the Xen `Connect` cmdlet in the block returns a `Could not find open sessions to any XenServers` error).

Then, I moved connecting to the `Xen` pool master server into the `background job`. This slowed operations because the making the connection takes a few seconds and was being done once for each VM. However, the `UI` remained responsive and I was able to use job completion data to update the `UI`.

How can I keep the `UI` responsive, update the `UI` with progress as each snapshot is created, and not be forced to connect to the server once per snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

> This solution does allow updates to be obtained in the the UI thread as the background job runs, but it does not keep the UI responsive. See my
>   response to Rohin below.

The solution was to move the entire loop into the `background job` and use the `Write-Progress` cmdlet to report progress on the `UI`. Credit for using the `Write-Progress` cmdlet in this scenario goes to [Ryan](http://www.get-blog.com/?p=132)

Here is a simple demo illustrating all the needed pieces

```
cls

## Job code
$ScriptBlockCode = 
{
    param($items)
    $retObj = @{}

    try
    {
        $error.clear()

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $items.Count; $i++)
        {

            #wait to simulate the time it takes to do work on item $i
            start-sleep -Seconds (get-random -Minimum 2 -Maximum 6)

            # Use Write-Progress to report the completion of each item for as long as the job runs (Can be used to updage the UI)
            # Use the -Completed argument to suppress displaying the progress bar 
            Write-Progress  -Id ($i+1) -Activity ("For UI Update: " + $items[$i] + " processing complete") -Status "Reporting" -PercentComplete ((($i+1)/$items.Count)*100) -Completed

            #Use a hashtable to report the status of each job. To be used in the calling code after the job status is no longer Running
            #simulate some items passing, some failing
            if ((get-random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 2) -eq 0)
            {
                $itemRet = [PSCustomObject]@{status="FAIL";details="some error description"}
            }
            else
            {
                $itemRet = [PSCustomObject]@{status="PASS";details=""}
            }

            $retObj.Add($items[$i],$itemRet)

        }

        return $retObj
    }
    catch
    {
        $itemRet = [PSCustomObject]@{status="ERROR";details=$error}
        $retObj.Add("FATAL",$itemRet)
        return $retObj
    }

}

cls

#clean up before starting
Get-Job -Name "UniqueJobName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Job
Get-Job -Name "UniqueJobName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Job

#simulate 5 pieces of work
$items = @("Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D", "Item E")

$job = Start-Job -Name "UniqueJobName" -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockCode -ArgumentList ($items)

#loop and update UI until job is done

$lastActivityId = -99

While ($job.State -eq "Running")
{
    $child = $job.ChildJobs[0]

    #update the UI only if progress has started and the ActivityId has not already been reported on and the Progress report is one I care about
    if ($child.Progress.Count -gt 0 -and $child.Progress[$child.Progress.Count - 1].ActivityId -ne $lastActivityId -and ($child.Progress[$child.Progress.Count - 1]).StatusDescription -eq "Reporting")
    {
        write-host "=============================="
        write-host "in progress updates"
        write-host "=============================="
        #use the progress properties, i.e., RecordType and PercentComplete to update the UI
        $child.Progress[$child.Progress.Count - 1]

        #store this Id so we can ignore progress until Id changes
        $lastActivityId = $child.Progress[$child.Progress.Count - 1].ActivityId
    }

    #period at which the UI is updated
    start-sleep -milliseconds 250
}

$retObj = Receive-Job -Name "UniqueJobName"

write-host "=============================="
write-host "receive job"
write-host "=============================="

# Because the job may finish before progress is captured 
# for each item, use the returned values to update the UI one last time
foreach ($key in $retObj.GetEnumerator())
{
    "retObj=" + $key.name + " " + $key.Value.status + " " + $key.Value.details
}

#cleanup
Get-Job -Name "UniqueJobName" | Stop-Job
Get-Job -Name "UniqueJobName" | Remove-Job
```

**Sample output**

```
==============================
in progress updates
==============================


ActivityId        : 1
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : For UI Update: Item A processing complete
StatusDescription : Reporting
CurrentOperation  : 
PercentComplete   : 20
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Completed

==============================
in progress updates
==============================
ActivityId        : 2
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : For UI Update: Item B processing complete
StatusDescription : Reporting
CurrentOperation  : 
PercentComplete   : 40
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Completed

==============================
in progress updates
==============================
ActivityId        : 3
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : For UI Update: Item C processing complete
StatusDescription : Reporting
CurrentOperation  : 
PercentComplete   : 60
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Completed

==============================
in progress updates
==============================
ActivityId        : 4
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : For UI Update: Item D processing complete
StatusDescription : Reporting
CurrentOperation  : 
PercentComplete   : 80
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Completed

==============================
receive job
==============================
retObj=Item D PASS 
retObj=Item E PASS 
retObj=Item A FAIL some error description
retObj=Item B FAIL some error description
retObj=Item C PASS
```

Comment: Are you able to move the UI around while it is processing or Interrupt the process in any way?

Comment: @RohinSidharth. As it turns out, no. Using Write-Progress in the background job does send updates to the UI thread (in the `While ($job.State -eq "Running")` loop), but the UI is otherwise frozen, so I can't even stop and remove the job by way of a button click. I won't use DoEvents() for all the reasons historically documented, so I guess my UI will stay frozen while the `While ($job.State -eq "Running")` loop executes. Bummer